# Data type with type constraint in Wadler - Essence of functional programming paper,

Tags: haskell, types, type-constraints, type-constructor

In Phil Wadler's paper : The essence of functional programming, Wadler describes the application of Monads using a simple interpreter program. The program is as shown below:

> A term is either a variable, a constant, a sum, a lambda expression,
>   or an application. The following will serve as test data.
>
> ```
> term0 = (App (Lam "x" (Add (Var "x") (Var "x"))) (Add (Con 10) (Con 11)))
> ```
>
> For our purposes, a monad is a triple `(M,unitM,bindM)` consisting of a
>   type constructor `M` and a pair of polymorphic functions.
>
> ```
> unitM :: a -> M a
> bindM :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
> ```

Then the interpreter program is described as:

```
type Name = String

data Value = Wrong
           | Num Int
           | Fun (Value -> M Value)
```

I do not see how `M Value` has been included here. My understanding that Haskell does not allow type constraints on data type constructors?

Further details:
The complete program is below:

```
type Name = String
data Term = Var Name
          | Con Int
          | Add Term Term
          | Lam Name Term
          | App Term Term
data Value = Wrong
           | Num Int
           | Fun (Value -> M Value)
type Environment = [(Name, Value)]
interp :: Term -> Environment -> M Value
interp (Var x) e = lookup x e
interp (Con i) e = unitM (Num i)
interp (Add u v) e = interp u e `bindM` (\a ->
                                            interp v e `bindM` (\b ->
                                                                  add a b))
interp (Lam x v) e = unitM (Fun (\a -> interp v ((x,a):e)))
interp (App t u) e = interp t e `bindM` (\f ->
                                             interp u e `bindM` (\a ->
                                                                     apply f a))

lookup :: Name -> Environment -> M Value
lookup x [] = unitM Wrong
lookup x ((y,b):e) = if x==y then unitM b else lookup x e

add :: Value -> Value -> M Value
add (Num i) (Num j) = unitM (Num (i+j))
add a b = unitM Wrong

apply :: Value -> Value -> M Value
apply (Fun k) a = k a
apply f a = unitM Wrong
```

As can be seen
`interp (Lam x v) e = unitM (Fun (\a -> interp v ((x,a):e)))` requires definition `data Value = ... | Func (Value -> M Value)`

I tried to implement `interp (Lam x v)` by using `data Value = ... | Func (Value -> Value)`, but it did not seem possible to me.

Comment: the M is supposed to be substituted with I, E, P, S, O, L, ... defined later in the article.

Answer (score 1):

M is not a constraint, it is a type constructor. So writing `M Value` is similar `[Value]`, `Maybe Value` etc. A constraint would be something like `Monad m => m Value`, where m is a type variable, not a type constructor and `Monad m` is the constraint (Monad is a type class).

In the paper, the definition of the type `M value` has not been presented, and it is later shown that you can give it different definitions (the definitions would involve defining `data M v = ...` and the functions `bindM` and `unitM`).

Edit: If you wanted to have a constraint, you would change the definition of value like this:

```
data Value m = Wrong
             | Num Int
             | Fun (Value m -> m (Value m))
```

And then have the constraint in the types of functions, e.g.:

```
interp :: Monad m => Term -> Environment -> m (Value m)
```

Comment: Got it, so basically it uses function bindM and unitM to introduce Monads rather than class Monad m. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve the same using class Monad m.. definition

Comment: This does not seem to work: data Value m = Wrong | Num Int | Func (Value -> m Value):  Expecting one more argument to ‘Value’
      Expected a type, but ‘Value’ has kind ‘(k0 -> *) -> *’
    • In the type ‘(Value -> m Value)’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘Func’
      In the data declaration for ‘Value’
   |
13 |                | Func (Value -> m Value)

Comment: Should be `Fun (Value m -> m (Value m)`